# How to call a function when user enter name in SharePoint People Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, people-picker

Need to grab user email from SharePoint people picker and show an alert. I have tried below options but unable to get an alert after adding the name in people picker.

```
var supervisorPicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict['Reportee_x0020_Of_f56eef23-35a8-4afe-8ffe-3cbf6993a7ad_$ClientPeoplePicker']

supervisorPicker.OnValueChangedClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInf)
{
     var supervisorEmail = supervisorPicker.GetAllUserInfo()[0].EntityData.Email
     showAlert(supervisorEmail);
};
```

and,

```
var sup = $().SPFindPeoplePicker({  
    peoplePickerDisplayName: "Reportee Of"  
});
if(sup != undefined){
    showAlert(sup.dictionaryEntries[0].Email);
}
```

my showAlert function is like this:

```
function showAlert(email){
    $.ajax({
         url: "http://xxxxxxx/DataService.svc/jsonData/"+email
    }).then(function(data) {
         alert(data.CL);
    });
}
```

Let me know what I am missing, and how can I grab a people picker change event to call a function and show the alert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to retrieve user email from custom people picker.

```
var user=[];
// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.  
    function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {  
        // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.  
        var schema = {};  
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';  
        schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;  
        schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;  
        schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;  
        schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;  
        schema['Width'] = '280px';  
        // Render and initialize the picker.  
        // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial   
        // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines  
        // picker properties.  
        SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);  
         SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.OnValueChangedClientScript=function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
            if(selectedUsersInfo.length>0)
            {
            user={selectedUsersInfo};
            //getInputUser(selectedUsersInfo);


            }
         };
    }
```